# How do I send GCM that when clicked opens URL?

Tags: push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, service-worker

I have set up service workers that subscribe to notifications. When Chrome is in the foreground the javascript controls the notification content and its `notificationclick` event handler will open a web page when the notification is clicked. (code not shown)

But when Chrome is in the background, the "Notification" payload is used for the notification content instead (js not activated), and when I click the notification it just opens Chrome without opening any web page at all.

I can live with having to handle two cases (Chrome was foreground or it wasn't), but clicking on them need to open a web page in both cases.

I'm thinking either my notification is missing some parameter, or I need my js to listen to a service-worker event that is triggered when Chrome opens. But I can't find a list of events that would be relevant.

Code that sends notifications:

```
import (
        gcm "github.com/google/go-gcm"
)
[...]
    res, err := gcm.SendHttp(apiKey, gcm.HttpMessage{
            // `destination` is the subscription endpoint provided by
            // serviceWorkerRegistration.pushManager.subscribe callback.
            RegistrationIds: []string{destination},

            ContentAvailable: true,
            TimeToLive:       &ttl,

            // This shows up when chrome is not open only. wut?
            Notification: &gcm.Notification{
                    Title: `Title here`,
                    Body:  "Blah blah lorem ipsum",
                    Sound: "default",
                    Color: "#ff0000",
                    //ClickAction: "something here?",
            },
    })
```

Comment: Not sure why this is tagged [android]

Comment: Since the behaviour is different depending on whether Chrome is in the background or foreground I assumed there is android code handling one of the cases. Maybe the ClickAction should be an Android intent or something (I don't know android). That's my reasoning at least, is it flawed?

Comment: What does Android have to do with this, is the code snippet for a chrome notification? Chrome can handle GCM notifications, `onMessage` will be fired when it receives a GCM. To display it, just use [`chrome.notifications`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/richNotifications), in which you'll set your URL call.

Comment: The code snippet sends a GCM notification, which seems to be picked up by Chrome when Chrome is in the foreground, and by the Android system when it's not. The content and icons in the notification are different. My terminology may be incorrect, but how is it *not* Android related?

Comment: My serviceworkers "self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {" shows no indication of triggering from the GCM message when Chrome is not in foreground. So *displaying* the notification isn't the problem.